# Check internet access Android

Tags: android, networking

I find a solution to check internet access but it didn't works on all devices

[How to check internet access on Android? InetAddress never times out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts/2001824)

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This solution works on Samsung galaxy tab 2 1.10 (Android 4.1.2).

But not on HTC wildfire (Android 2.3.5)

On the second device netInfo is always null

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per below Documentation return null is becasue of NO Default network (Data network) available.

Looks like only isConnected() can help you to identify will it connected or Not.
i tried on 4 Phones (Sony Ericson, samsung (2 phones ) , Nexus Lg) it shows the perfect  result as required.

public NetworkInfo `getActiveNetworkInfo ()`

Added in API level 1
Returns details about the currently active default data network. When connected, this network is the default route for outgoing connections. You should always check isConnected() before initiating network traffic.

> This may return null when there is no default network.

Returns
a NetworkInfo object for the current default network or null if no network default network is currently active
This method requires the call to hold the `permission ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not enough...

With ConnectivityManager, you know if your phone has a connectivity available (wifi or 4G). But you aren't sure if you really have internet access (you can be connected to a wifi spot with limited connection or need an identification.

After testing the connection (using ConnectivityManager), you have to ping a web site.

Here is the best answer that explain how and what to do :
[Ping a Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27312494/968538)